# How to add widget area to a Woocommerce product category page before footer?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How to add a widget area to all Woocommerce product category pages before the footer?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by editing the woocommerce/archive-product.php as needed

Comment: No, thats not the correct way! You would lose changes after an update. Just do a hook

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using an action, do something like this:

```
function prefix_add_my_widget() {
 echo '<div id="my-sidebar" class="sidebar">';
 dynamic_sidebar( 'my-sidebar' );
 echo '</div>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'prefix_add_my_widget'  );
```